# Unable to reinstall MacOS, Prohibited sign after booting to bootable USB installer

Tags: macos, usb, startup, ssd, install

So I have this very old Macbook Pro, this was given to me and it's 7 years since then. I don't know the specific model but the previous OS installed is `OS X El Capitan 10.11.4`.

**CREATION OF BOOTABLE FLASHDRIVE**

So I go to the official support of apple on [how to create a bootable USB flash drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). I downloaded the `El Capitan 10.11` since it's the previous OS I have and I want to avoid compatibility issues, I just want to do a clean install. I have a very fast internet connection and I'm pretty sure that the installer I downloaded is not corrupted. I do this on the Macbook Pro itself and the creation of Bootable USB Flashdrive is successful. I do this just in case the online installation failed.

**INSTALLATION USING ONLINE INSTALLER**

Now, I booted into the system recovery first and from the Disk Utility, I completely erase the content of my SSD storage. Then I go back and use the option of online installation, upon signing in I got an error saying `This item is temporarily unavailable`, I tried it again and again but it won't proceed. I found by searching that this is a known issue and the option is by using an offline installer by creating a bootable installer which is to happen that I have from the beginning.

**INSTALLATION USING OFFLINE INSTALLER**

So I plugin my bootable USB Flashdrive, I press and hold the `OPTION` button while booting, I selected the USB Flashdrive which is in the boot list. The Apple logo shows up with the loading bar, after that this happened;

[image]

I tried it again, power off the machine, and boot then the same thing happened. Apple logo shows up with a loading bar after that the prohibited sign shows up again.

I search and people say that this is something related to the corrupted installer. I have fast internet and 6GB of El Capitan DMG file took only 5 minutes, well I thought maybe they are right so I opened up my Windows computer, and using VirtualBox with `High Sierra` installed on it I recreated the Bootable Flashdrive. I downloaded the El Capitan installer again and create it, but after booting the same issue. I tried with other installers such as `Sierra 10.12`, `El Capitan 10.11`, `Yosemite 10.10` but they all have the same issue.

So what does this mean in the first place? And how can I push the installation?

Comment: Since you found a solution from an accepted answer to a [previously posted question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226983/mac-wont-boot-from-usb-drive-prohibited-sign), I voted to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, there is a missing step and Apple failed to provide it. Seeing this prohibited sign on the boot means either the installer is corrupted or because of a security permission issue on USB Flashdrive.

1. Create a bootable USB Flashdrive, as stated from the [official](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) support of Apple.
2. Once it's done, and the creation is successful, `Uncheck` the `Ignore ownership`. To do this, simply `right-click` on the bootable USB Flashdrive you created, at the bottom of the window click to expand the option `Sharing & Permissions:` then you will see the `ignore ownership`, uncheck it, and don't forget to save by clicking the `lock` icon.

Found the same solution from this link.

https://www.lifewire.com/create-emergency-os-x-boot-device-2260173

[Mac won't boot from USB drive: Prohibited sign](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226983/mac-wont-boot-from-usb-drive-prohibited-sign)